# dplyr (version 0.4.3) - Issue with group_by and slice

Tags: r, dplyr

I've created a simple example where the objective is to get, for each group, top N rows in terms of a column and calculate the average value of another column.

In this example I'm using the `mtcars` dataset, my grouping variable is `am` (0s and 1s), the column I'm sorting/arranging is `hp` and the average values I want are of column `disp`.

It is a simple and straight-forward process and for the arranging and picking top N rows in terms of `hp` I can use (a) `top_n` or (b) `arrange` and `slice`. In case (a) it works well, but in case (b) it seems that after `slice` I have to group again.

Is that a reasonable thing when using `slice`? Why is the grouping lost?

```
library(dplyr) # version 0.4.3

# example dataframe
dt = data.frame(mtcars)


# CASE (a)
# using top_n
dt %>% group_by(am) %>% top_n(n=4,hp) %>% summarise(MeanDisp = mean(disp))

#      am MeanDisp
#    (dbl)    (dbl)
# 1     0  402.500
# 2     1  223.025


# CASE (b)
# using slice
dt %>% group_by(am) %>% arrange(desc(hp)) %>% slice(1:4) %>% summarise(MeanDisp = mean(disp))

# Error: corrupt 'grouped_df', contains 8 rows, and 32 rows in groups


# using slice and grouping again
dt %>% group_by(am) %>% arrange(desc(hp)) %>% slice(1:4) %>% group_by(am) %>% summarise(MeanDisp = mean(disp))

#      am MeanDisp
#    (dbl)    (dbl)
# 1     0  402.500
# 2     1  223.025
```

Comment: Per this [github issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1405), I think this has been fixed in the development version (and I can't reproduce using dplyr_0.4.3.9000).

Comment: Great. Haven't used the dev version yet and I couldn't remember if this was OK in a previous dplyr version. Thanks.